# Reaplace NA values from different columns

Tags: r

R replace problem

Can't replace in the dataset NA values from different columns with a median of the same column with NA value.

Titanic.new is the dataset.

I have tried:

```
fun3<-function(x)
{
      column.numeric<-x[,sapply(x,is.numeric)]
      column.numeric[which(is.na(column.numeric))]<-median(column.numeric,na.rm = TRUE)
      return(column.numeric)
}
    fun3(titanic.new)
```

I'm getting an error:

> Error in median.default(column.numeric, na.rm = TRUE) :
>   need numeric data

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We can do some modification in the function.  Loop through the columns of the dataset, find whether the `type` is numeric ('i1') -> return a logical `vector`.  Subset the data using the vector, loop through the columns with `lapply` and `replace` the NAs in the column with the `median` of that column

```
fun3<-function(x){
    i1 <- sapply(x,is.numeric)
    x[i1] <- lapply(x[i1], function(y) replace(y, is.na(y), median(y, na.rm = TRUE)))
    x
 }
fun3(titanic.new)
```

---

Or it can be done with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
titanic.new %>% 
     mutate_if(is.numeric, list(~ replace(., is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```

which can be wrapped in a function as well

```
fun4 <- function(x) {
       x %>%
           mutate_if(is.numeric,
               list(~ replace(., is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE))))
     }
```

---

Also, this can be done more compactly with `na.aggregate`

```
library(zoo)
i1 <-  sapply(titanic.new, is.numeric)
titanic.new[i1] <- na.aggregate(titanic.new[i1], FUN = median)
```

Comment: what is y stands for? the dataset? the input for fun3 function?

Comment: @Chen890  Here, we use anonymous function (lambda function - `function(y)` ).  When we loop through `lapply`,  it is looping through each of the column, so, 'y' refer to that particular column

Comment: but i want do the function for all columns, not only one from the dataset.

Comment: @Chen890  Have you tested the function?  It is doing for all the `numeric` columns as you have showed in the code

Comment: dont have library zoo or tidyverse

Comment: @Chen890  No need.  You can still use the `fun3` which doesn't require that

Comment: @Chen890  Sorry, I forgot the return x.  Now, you check `fun3`

Comment: @Chen890  Let me show a reproducible example.  `data(iris); iris[1:5, 3] <- NA; fun3(iris)` works fine for me.  Here, I am assuming that your data is `data.frame`

Comment: @Chen890  You haven't provided a reproducible example nor the error.  I showed u one with a reproducible example

Comment: @Chen890  The error in your post is based on the function applied on the data.frame instead of a column.  Here, I don't see that case

Comment: download the trian.csv file and try to do what you have proposed

Comment: @Chen890  Sorry, I can't download it because it asks for signup and other stuff